# como hacer una consulta de 3 tablas con caracteres diferentes en Mysql

Tags: sql

buenas noches alguien me puede ayudar diciéndome como hacer esta consulta por favor

*mostrar el numero de personas que vivan en "Germany" y que estudian "Frances"*

mis tablas son

```
estudiantes 
-id 
-nombre
-idpais
-ididioma

pais
-idpais
-pais

idioma
-ididioma
-idioma
```

Comment: agrega lo que has tratado, aunque no te de el resultado esperado; es importante mostrar el interés a través de los intentos

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También  leer [ask]. Solo te voy a orientar. Debes hacer uso de [SQL INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) para unir tus tablas, [SQL WHERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) para aplicar tus condiciones y [SQL COUNT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) para saber la cantidad. Realiza el intento y nos cuentas.

Answer (score -2):

deberías de estudiar las funciones de agregación:

```
select idioma, pais, count(*) from pais p
inner join estudiantes e on p.idpais = e.idpais
inner join idioma i on e.ididioma = i.ididioma
where p.pais='Germany'
and i.idioma='Frances'
group by  i.idioma, p.pais
```

Saludos

Comment: deberías leer [answer] y hacer el [tour] para saber que preguntas que no muestran aunque sea un mínimo avance no se deben responder

Comment: además deberías explicar tu respuesta pues solo poner código es de baja calidad

Comment: @Victor, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. En mi opinión, tu código va orientado a la buena calidad, aunque si te fijas bien, incluir el idioma, el país y luego agrupar por ellos, queda de más. Ya que vas a incluir solo un País y un Idioma en el `where`, puedes simplemente contar los registros del resultado. Un saludo y ¡gracias por el aporte!